# Wordpress User Role allow acces only to Contact Form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a custom user role, called form_editor. I want this user to only be able to edit contact form 7.

THis is what I have so far

```
$form_editor_role = add_role(
    'form_editor',
    __( 'Form Editor' ),
    array(
        'read'         => true,  // true allows this capability
        'edit_posts'   => true,
        'delete_posts' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
    )
);

$role = get_role( 'form_editor' );
if(!$role->has_cap('cfdb7_access')){
    $role->add_cap( 'cfdb7_access' );
}
```

Right not it doesn't have access to posts. It has view access to contact forms, but no edit permissions.

Answer (score 1):

try adding `publish_pages` and add `remove_role('form_editor');` to refresh current role

```
remove_role('form_editor');
add_role('form_editor', __('Form Editor'), array(
    'read' => true, // true allows this capability
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'delete_posts' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
    'publish_pages' => true
));

$role = get_role('form_editor');
if (!$role->has_cap('cfdb7_access')) {
    role->add_cap('cfdb7_access');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [link](https://www.role-editor.com/contact-form-7-plugin-menu-access/). The Contact Form 7 uses the built-in user capabilities

```
wpcf7_edit_contact_form => publish_pages
wpcf7_edit_contact_forms => publish_pages
wpcf7_read_contact_forms => edit_posts
wpcf7_delete_contact_form => publish_pages
wpcf7_manage_integration => manage_options
```

for editing permission you should give `publish_pages` capability to your new role like this:

```
$role = get_role( 'form_editor' );
$role->add_cap( 'publish_pages' );
```

Comment: This still holds true as of CF7 v5.2.1, `publish_pages` cap is required for `wpcf7_edit_contact_forms` to work.

Answer (score 0):

The CF7 plugin was written at the initial stages of WordPress, prior to the framework maturing its dashboard integration core code and as such, the plugin author created a number of admin pages that extend admin classes in order to integrate the form editor pages.  The WordPress core code evolved to the point where a standard mechanism exists today for plugin integration in the dashboard so as to leverage a lot of the functionality that is already built into the admin interface, while the CF7 plugin code has maintained its legacy code to the point that many existing core functionality does not apply to the CF7 plugin.  For example [adding custom columns](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-column-in-dashboard-table-list/) to the form table list.

The CF7 forms are stored as a custom post type `wpcf7_contact_form`, however, the table list and editor pages are both custom admin pages (as opposed to the `edit.php` and post.php respectively).  Getting to WP core standard functionality to work on the CF7 plugin will always be a challenge.  It is this very reason which led me to develop a plugin extension to bring back the CF7 plugin into the WP core standard.  I wrote the [Smart Grid-Layout design Extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) in order to be able to create responsive grid-layout forms by creating a new form editor that integrates a UI designer.  As a result, the table list and form editor pages are now WP core pages, which leverage the full functionality of the framework.

Using this extension, fine-tuning user role access can be achieved using the WordPress capabilities functionality by either [defining a new role](https://wedevs.com/98266/add-custom-user-roles-wordpress/) or [adding additional capabilities to an existing role](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13413/how-to-add-a-capability-to-a-user-role). The CF7 capabilities that allow you to control access are,

```
 'edit_posts' => 'wpcf7_edit_contact_forms'; //controls access to form table
 'edit_others_posts' => 'wpcf7_edit_others_contact_forms'; //controls access to forms created by other users.
 'edit_published_posts'  => 'wpcf7_edit_published_contact_forms'; //ability to edit published forms.
 'delete_posts'  => 'wpcf7_delete_contact_forms'; //delete forms.
 'delete_published_posts'  => 'wpcf7_delete_published_contact_forms'; //delete published forms.
 'delete_others_posts'  => 'wpcf7_delete_others_contact_forms'; //delete forms created by other users.
 'publish_posts'  => 'wpcf7_publish_contact_forms'; //publish forms, else status are set as pending.
```

so for example, creating a new role for a form editor,

```
add_action('init', 'create_cf7editor_role');
function create_cf7editor_role(){
  add_role('cf7_editor', 'Form Editor',
    array('wpcf7_edit_contact_forms'=>1,
    'wpcf7_edit_others_contact_forms'=>1,
    'wpcf7_edit_published_contact_forms'=>1,
    'wpcf7_read_contact_forms'=>1,
    'wpcf7_publish_contact_forms'=>1,
    'wpcf7_delete_contact_forms'=>1,
    'wpcf7_delete_published_contact_forms'=>1,
    'wpcf7_delete_others_contact_forms'=>1)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just see this  and had apply a trick . I have disable contact form option for all user expect form_editor. will it be good.

```
function remove_menu_pages() {

    //global $user_ID;

    
    
     if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
 $user = wp_get_current_user();
 $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;
if($roles[0]!='form_editor')
{
    remove_menu_page('wpcf7');
}
}
    
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_menu_pages' );
```